# Yeoman: how to avoid file overwrite conflict message when modifying file created by subgenerator?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

### Overview

I am creating a yeoman generator that will generate a customized angular app.  It will be generating custom angular controllers and services.

While I could simply take a current angular template, as generated by the [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme), add my code, and then save this as a template in my generator, I prefer to have the generator call the "official" angular generator (previously installed by the user) as a subgenerator at runtime, so I don't have to synchronize my templates every time the angular generator template changes.

### Problem

I have this working, but the only problem is when, from my generator, I add my code to the file generated by the subgenerator (e.g a controller), I get the message:

```
 conflict app/scripts/controllers/mycontroller.js
? Overwrite app/scripts/controllers/mycontroller.js? overwrite
    force app/scripts/controllers/mycontroller.js
```

Is there a way I can get the file generated by the subgenerator before it's written to disk, so I can edit it, without generating the overwrite prompt?

I think it's confusing to be prompted about overwriting a file that is being created for the first time.

### Data

In reading the [yeoman doc](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html), it makes it sound like generators and subgenerators share the same "soft" in-memory filesystem:

*"As asynchronous APIs are harder to use, Yeoman provide a synchronous file-system API where every file gets written to an in-memory file system and are only written to disk once when Yeoman is done running. **This memory file system is shared between all composed generators."***

But it appears that the subgenerator writes the files to disk and not the in-memory file system.  Unfortunately, I do not have control over the subgenerator, as it's the standard angular yeoman generator.

Here is my generator (scroll down to portion marked "Relevant Portion"):

```
'use strict';   
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
 prompting: function () {
    var done = this.async();

    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(yosay(
      'Welcome to the epic ' + chalk.red('AngularVr') + ' generator!'
    ));

    var prompts = [{
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'someOption',
      message: 'Would you like to enable this option?',
      default: true
    }];

    this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
      this.props = props;
      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  writing: { 
    app: function () {
          this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath('_vt_marker.json'),
        this.destinationPath('vt_marker.json')
      );
    },

====================== Relevant Portion ===============
  subgenerators: function () {
      this.log("now executing subgenerators");
      this.composeWith('angular:controller',  {args: ['mycontroller']} );

      this.log("now done with subgeneration");
  }, 

  subgenerators_read: function () {
// add a new line to generated file..this generates overwrite prompt
    var fp = this.destinationPath('app/scripts/controllers/mycontroller.js');
    var fc = this.fs.read(fp);
    fc += '\nhello there\n';
    this.fs.write(fp, fc);
  },

});
```

This is my first attempt at writing a yeoman generator.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Just discovered that specifying 'this.conflicter.force = true' on the 'subgenerators_read' step, suppresses the message.  I suppose this can do for now, but it kind of seems like a scary solution.  I hope someone can come up with a better way.

Comment: Oh no, don't do that :|

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably just that either your generator or the generator-angular is running on an old version of `yeoman-generator`.

Latest version at this time is 0.20.3 https://www.npmjs.com/package/yeoman-generator

Comment: my generator is "0.20.3", but I can't say about the angular generator.  But like you said in your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010498/composewith-in-yeoman-generator-not-emitting-an-end-event-and-thus-not-driving/33094197#33094197, the angular generator is using an older version of yeoman.  If I can verify this is the problem, I will update the ticket.  Thanks for your help.